# Evaluation of the integrals $ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}} $ and $\int\frac{3x^5dx}{1+x^{12}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am struggling to find the values of these integrals after trying many substitution it did't worked for me

1) $$ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}} $$
2) $$ \int_{}^{}\frac{3x^5dx}{1+x^{12}} $$

Comment: 1) Have you tried completing the square under the squareroot?   2) Have you tried u = x^6 ?

Comment: can you complete the square ? i got the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

For $$\int_0^a\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}=\int_0^a\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(a-x)}}=\int_0^a\frac{dx}{|a|\sqrt{\frac xa(1-\frac xa)}}$$

Putting $x=a\sin^2y,dx=2a\sin y\cos y dy$ and as $x=0\implies y=0;x=a\implies y=\frac\pi2$

$$\int_0^a\frac{dx}{|a|\sqrt{\frac xa(1-\frac xa)}}=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{2a\sin y\cos y dy}{|a|\sin y\cos y}=\frac 2{\text{ sign }(a)}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}dy$$

$$\text{Similarly for the integral }\frac1{\sqrt{x(x-a)}},\text{ put } x=a\sec^2y$$

$$\text{Similarly for the integral }\frac1{\sqrt{x(x+a)}},\text{ put } x=a\tan^2y$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint (a):** Use change of variables, then trigonometric substitutions.
\begin{align}
\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}
=
&
\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+2\cdot \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)x-x^2}}
\\
=
&
\int_0^a \frac{\left(x-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \right)^\prime dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \right)^2}}
\end{align}
If $u=\left(x-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \right)$ then $du=\left(x-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \right)^\prime dx$ and we have the new integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^a  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}=&\int_{\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}a}  \frac{du}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-u^2}}
\end{align}
Now you can proceed by trigonometric substitution $u=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\sin \theta$ then $ du=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\cos\theta \, d\theta $ and 
$$
\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-u^2}=
\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\sin^2\theta}=
\left|\frac{a}{2}\right|\cdot \left|\cos\theta\right|
$$

**Hint (b):** Use change of variables and partial fractions in
\begin{align} 
\int\frac{3x^5dx}{1+x^{12}}
=
&
\int\frac{3}{6}\frac{(x^6)^\prime dx}{1+(x^{6})^2}
\\
\end{align}

Comment: I think, you need $u=\frac a2\sec\theta,$

Comment: what's the derivative of $\sec\theta?$

Comment: @lab yes, you are right.

Comment: I think the first solution may not be correct.

Comment: @Elias, the first solution is horrible wrong. How the sign of $x^2$ has changed?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Now I think my answer is correct and free of errors.

Comment: @Elias, if you put $u=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\sec \theta,$ $$\sqrt{(\frac a2)^2-u^2}=\sqrt{-a^2\tan^2\theta}=|a\tan\theta|\sqrt{-1}$$ leading to complex number,right? Please find the hints in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first integral, write

$$ax = \left (\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 - \left ( \frac{a}{2}-x\right)^2$$

and substitute $y = a/2-x$, then $y=(a/2) \sin{\theta}$.  The result I get is $\pi$, independent of $a$.

For the second integral, substitute $y=x^6$, and use

$$\int \frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \arctan{y}+C$$