# Troubles with an identity with integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $T$ be the operator acting as $$Tf(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}}dt$$

Prove that $$T^2(f)(x) =  \int_0^x f(t)dt, \; x \in [0,1]$$

I tried but I can't get that formula! I used fubini and stuff like that but I got nothing. Anybody can give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: This is a convolution integral, which makes it a natural for the Laplace transform. Just extend $f$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem, we have that
$$\begin{align}T^2(f)(x)&=T(Tf)(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^t \frac{f(s)}{\sqrt{t-s}}ds}{\sqrt{x-t}}dt=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^x f(s)ds\int_s^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{x-t}\sqrt{t-s}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^x f(s)ds\int_0^{x-s}\frac{du}{\sqrt{(x-s)u-u^2}}
=\int_0^x f(s)ds
\end{align}$$
where $u=t-s$. For the last step, by using the hints given at [Evaluation of the integrals $ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}} $ and $\int\frac{3x^5dx}{1+x^{12}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463814/evaluation-of-the-integrals-int-0a-fracdx-sqrtax-x2-and-int-f) , you should be able to show that
$$\int_0^{x-s}\frac{du}{\sqrt{(x-s)u-u^2}}=\pi.$$

Comment: Dear downvoter, please help me to improve my answer. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$T^2(f)(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^x \frac{\dfrac{1}{\pi} \displaystyle\int_0^t \frac{f(s)}{\sqrt{t-s}}ds}{\sqrt{x-t}}dt=\frac1{\pi^2}\int_{t=0}^x\int_{s=0}^t\frac{f(s)}{\sqrt{x-t}\sqrt{t-s}}ds\,dt.$$

By swapping the order of integration,

$$I=\frac1{\pi^2}\int_{s=0}^x\int_{t=s}^x\frac{f(s)}{\sqrt{x-t}\sqrt{t-s}}dt\,ds$$

and

$$\int_{s}^x\frac1{\sqrt{x-t}\sqrt{t-s}}dt=\int_{0}^{x-s}\frac1{\sqrt{x-s-t}\sqrt{t}}dt=\int_{0}^1\frac{\sqrt{x-s}}{\sqrt{x-s}\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{x-s}\sqrt{t}}dt\\
=\int_{0}^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{t}}dt.$$

The final integral is indeed a constant and I leave it to you to show that it equals $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Extend $f$ to be $0$ on $[1,\infty)$ so that you can view your integral operator as the convolution of $f$ with $1/\sqrt{\pi t}$. The Laplace transform of $Tf$ is then given by
$$
         \mathscr{L}\{Tf\}=\mathscr{L}\{f\}\mathscr{L}\{1/\sqrt{\pi t}\} \\
       \mathscr{L}\{T^2f\}=\mathscr{L}\{f\}\mathscr{L}\{1/\sqrt{\pi t}\}^2
$$
Then
$$
  \mathscr{L}\{1/\sqrt{\pi}t\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}dt \\
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s t}}s dt \\
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi u}}du \\
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-1+1/2}du \\
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}}\Gamma(1/2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}.
$$
Finally,
$$
    \mathscr{L}\{T^2f\} =\frac{1}{s}\mathscr{L}\{f\} \\
     T^2 f = \int_0^x f(t)dt.
$$